# Map and replace not decrypting simple senteces and returns array of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, cryptography

I'm trying to decode the  name of 10 products of the following array(parsed json):

```
[
  {
    id: 9628920,
    name: 'Lævæ & Se¢æ 10,2 Kg Sæmsung E¢ø ßußßle ßræn¢æ ¢øm 09 Prøgræmæs de Lævægem',
    quantity: 57,
    price: 3719.7,
    category: 'Eletrodomésticos'
  },
  {
    id: 1316334,
    name: 'Refrigerædør ßøttøm Freezer Ele¢trølux de 02 Pørtæs Frøst Free ¢øm 598 Litrøs',
    quantity: 12,
    price: 3880.23,
    category: 'Eletrodomésticos'
  },
     and so on ......
]
```

I could not add the whole array with its 10 elements the question, that's why I wrote "and so on..."

I'm using this code, but decryptedData is receaving an array of 10 undefined values when I `console.log()` it:

```
 const  decryptedData = parsedData.map(product=>{
    product.name.replace('æ', 'a');
    product.name.replace('ø', 'o');
    product.name.replace('¢', 'c');
    product.name.replace('ß', 'b');
    
});

console.log(decryptedData);
```

Comment: You are not returning anything!

Comment: If you console.log parsedData, does it output the array?

Comment: replace with a string only does one occurrence, The string is not updated

Comment: @ent3r_ Dude that's the shorthand of arrow function which returns the statement! when you use {} it'll become the body of your function! Read the document on the link you sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the updated **product** and assign the value for each replace.

For the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method you need to use a regex pattern:

```
string.replace(/æ/g, 'a');
```

The pattern means: change each **æ** in the string with a **a**

```js
var parsedData = [
    {
        id: 9628920,
        name: 'Lævæ & Se¢æ 10,2 Kg Sæmsung E¢ø ßußßle ßræn¢æ ¢øm 09 Prøgræmæs de Lævægem',
        quantity: 57,
        price: 3719.7,
        category: 'Eletrodomésticos'
    },
    {
        id: 1316334,
        name: 'Refrigerædør ßøttøm Freezer Ele¢trølux de 02 Pørtæs Frøst Free ¢øm 598 Litrøs',
        quantity: 12,
        price: 3880.23,
        category: 'Eletrodomésticos'
    }
];

const decryptedData = parsedData.map(product=>{
    product.name = product.name.replace(/æ/g, 'a')
                               .replace(/ø/g, 'o')
                               .replace(/¢/g, 'c')
                               .replace(/ß/g, 'b');
    return product;
});

console.log(decryptedData);
```

Comment: It worked thank you !, but what is this /æ/g, and what does it mean ?

Comment: @RobertVitoriano did you know the use of function `map` is creating a new array and it's mutating the original array? why not just loop over the original array?

Answer (score -1):

The handler of the function `map` doesn't return anything, you should return in this case the object `product`, however, the use of function `map` is not ok, use the function `forEach` instead.

Additionally, you should use a Regex with the flag global `/g` in order to replace all the matches, and finally store the result in `product.name`.

```
 parsedData.forEach(product=>{
   product.name = product.name.replace(/æ/g, 'a');
   product.name = product.name.replace(/ø/g, 'o');
   product.name = product.name.replace(/¢/g, 'c');
   product.name = product.name.replace(/ß/g, 'b');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You need a `g` flag regex to replace all occurrences

Comment: Note you can also chain replace() and cut out a lot of the redundant code

Comment: @charlietfl yeah sure, but that's not the goal of my answer